# Lost some packet using Python sniffing module

Tags: scapy, packet-capture, sniffing

I've tried almost all Python sniffing modules (pcapy, winpcapy, pypcap, scapy, socket).

I got always the same problem that I lost a part of the packets (about 1% ~ 10%).

But at same time with Wireshark and tcpdump packets are never lost; maybe performance? Or try to do something with multiprocess?

Comment: please provide some code that you're using to collect. packet loss can depend on the options of how scapy is configured

Comment: ok.i  using some example code from www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/:
from scapy.all import *
from scapy.layers import http
def http_header():
    do something;
packet=sniff(prn=http_header,store=0)
and how can i check the scapy configured.
thx!

Answer (score 1):

from this code

```
from scapy.all import *
from scapy.layers import http 
def http_header():
    do something

packet=sniff(prn=http_header,store=0)
```

`store 0` is the problem. it basically says only process packets as soon as possible, don't buffer. run the same code with `sniff(prn=http_header)` and you won't drop any packets

Comment: thank your answer, i try it agin with sniff(prn=http_header),but its still lost,and i found python process memory leak, actually,i will run the program a long time. so i need it.

Comment: @Poisonx, did you find the solution? I also tried without store=0, still have package lost.